# pyspark split dataframe by two columns without creating a folder structure for the 2nd

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Two part question.

I have a pyspark dataframe that I'm reading from a list of JSON files in my azure blob storage.

after some simple ETL I need to move this from blob storage to a datalake as a parquet file, simple so far.

I'm unsucessfully trying to efficiently write this into a folder defined by two columns, one which is a date column and the other an ID

using `partitionBy` gets me close

```
id | date                | nested_json_data | path
1  | 2019-01-01 12:01:01 | {data : [data]}  | dbfs:\mnt\..
1  | 2019-01-01 12:01:02 | {data : [data]}  | dbfs:\mnt\..


df.write.partitionBy("id","date").('dbfs:\mnt\curated\...')
```

this gives me a folder structure as follows :

```
mnt --- |
         -- ...\1--|
                    --...\1\date=2019-01-01%2012:01:01\{file}.pq
                    --...\1\date=2019-01-01%2012:01:02\{file}.pq
```

what I'm after is a single folder for each unique `id` column with each file split out by date.

```
mnt --- |
         -- ...\1--|
                    --...\1 -- |
                               |filename_2019_01_01_12_0_01.pq
                               |filename_2019_01_01_12_0_02.pq
```

2nd question is that my date folder name is coming out like `Date=2019-12-23 13%3A26%3A00`

is there a method to not have that without changing the Schema of my spark dataframe? if i have to create a temp column then that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that using only `partitionBy` with Spark. As far as I know, Spark always write partitions as `partition=value` folders. See [spark partition discovery](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#partition-discovery).

What you can do is write with `partitionBy("id", "date")` in a temporary folder then list recursively the files and move/rename them to get the structure you want.

For the date format, you can transform it before writing:

```
df = df.withColumn("date") date_format(col("date"), "yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss")
```

Here is some code to list recursively all part files from the temporary folder and copy them to the destination folder with rename. It uses Hadoop FS, you can adapt it for your case:

```
conf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
Path = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
FileUtil = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil


# list all files from staging folder
staging_folder_path = Path("/tmp/folder/")
fs_staging_f = staging_folder_path.getFileSystem(conf)
staging_files = fs_staging_f.listFiles(staging_folder_path, True)

# filter files that have names starting with 'part"
part_files = []
while staging_files.hasNext():
    part_file_path = staging_files.next().getPath()
    if part_file_path.getName().startswith("part"):
        part_files.append(part_file_path)

# add some logic here to flatten the date folders and add the date pattern to filenames

# move files
FileUtil.copy(....)
```

Comment: ah I was looking to avoid such laborious looping but I guess I'll just have to dive in! thanks mr Bishop, I'll take your word this is the correct answer =)