# Writing large spark data frame as parquet to s3 bucket

Tags: pyspark, parquet, aws-glue

**My Scenario**

- I have a spark data frame in a AWS glue job with 4 million records
- I need to write it as a SINGLE parquet file in AWS s3

**Current code**

```
file_spark_df.write.parquet("s3://"+target_bucket_name)
```

**Issue**
the above code creates 100+ files each 17.8 to 18.1 MB in size , guess its some default break down size

**Ques 1 : How do I create just one file ? for one spark data frame ?**
I checked https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html didnt find any parameter to set

**Ques 2 : How do I specify the name of the file**
I tried ...

```
file_df.write.parquet("s3://"+target_bucket_name+"/"+target_file_name)
```

It created 100+ files inside "s3://"+target_bucket_name+"/"+target_file_name

**Ques 3 : How do I specify the name of the file**
I need to create sub folders inside base3 bucket following code can do the job

```
file_df.write.parquet("s3://"+target_bucket_name+"/"+today_date+"/"+target_file_name)
```

not sure if its the best way ... or there is a better way ?

Comment: Use `coalesce(1)` to write into one file : `file_spark_df.coalesce(1).write.parquet("s3_path")`.

Comment: thanks this worked ... any inputs on 2,3 ? also i need to check if folder already exists ... if so first delete then write .... can you post your comment as an answer so that i can accept it

Comment: To specify an output filename, you'll have to rename the `part*` files written by Spark. For example write to a temp folder, list part files, rename and move to the destination. you can see my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59535517/1386551) for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.repartition(1)` or as @blackbishop says, coalesce(1) to say "I only want one partition on the output"

- use a subdir as things don't like writing to the root path. It's not a normal directory
- filenames get chosen by the partition code, best to list the dir for the single file and rename.

it should look something like this

```scala
val dest = "s3://"+target_bucket_name + "/subdir"
val destPath = newPath(dest)
val fs = Filesystem.get(destPath, conf) // where conf is the hadoop conf from your spark conf
fs.delete(destPath, true)
file_spark_df.parquet.repartition(1).write.(dest)

// at this point there should be only one file in the dest dir
val files = fs.listStatus(destPath)   // array of fileStatus of size == 1
if (fs.size != 1) throw new IOException("Wrong number of files in " + destPath)
fs.rename(files[0].getPath(), new Path(destPath, "final-filename.parquet")
```

(note, code written @ console, not compiled, tested etc. You should get the idea though)

Comment: with repartition(1) i get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'repartition

Comment: what is FileSystem ? do i need to import something ? is there a way i can specify a destination file name ... i dont want random file name

Comment: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.